# Is there any way to automatically bind Redux and Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, redux, polymer-1.0, web-component

I want to use Polymer and its web components.

I've already made some applications using React+Redux, and I really like the approach used by Redux to deal with states and actions.

My questions are:

- Is there any way to integrate them?
- Is there any library that automatically binds redux with web componentes (just like `react-redux`)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a [polymer-redux](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux) element that allows you to inject the store into various Polymer elements and also provides mechanism to bind data slices from the store to polymer properties.

I am using it in one of my apps and it works just fine. I summarized my experience with it [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/653#issuecomment-203611143)

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest my library, [redux-store-element](https://github.com/lastmjs/redux-store-element). It is a custom element that provides access to the Redux API. Just pop the `redux-store` element into any component that needs it. For example, here's the entire API of the element:

- Hook up your root reducer: `<redux-store root-reducer="[[rootReducer]]"></redux-store>`
- Dispatch actions: `<redux-store action="[[action]]"></redux-store>`
- Listen for state changes: `<redux-store on-statechange="mapStateToThis"></redux-store>`